# Unethical conduct in the workplace

Tags: ethics, south-africa

I've briefly read information on harrasment at work from south african law perspective. They suggest that a witness should corroborate the discriminating statements made by co-worker.

A brief story of what happened.
I was walking down the hallway when the coworker in question says I should take his cup of coffee to the kitchen. I replied, "I'm not a domestic worker". He responded with, "Are you sure? You look like one".

What are my options, to pursue this matter further?

Comment: That's not "unethical", that's abuse, plain and simple.

Comment: We're not attorneys.  Have you tried human resources?

Comment: I'll try human resources. Unfortunately, the company doesn't follow high standards for human resources. I'll ask a labour lawyer. But, they're damn expensive. From experience, human resources in south africa is not up to standards with international industries

Comment: Attorneys are sharks. No integrity. They study advanced logic for what, only to delay and run your bank account dry

Comment: If HR won't help much and legal action is too expensive, and likely not that helpful here either, your list of options are limited. Find another job, or completely avoid speaking to/looking at the person again.

Comment: Noted. I'll ignore the person. Anyway i deserve a better job

Comment: @pay, You'll always have some bad apple. Just changing jobs is not a solution. These people need to be put in their place

Comment: If you don't have a good witness who will corroborate your story,  there's not much point in going to anyone, for a matter like this.

Comment: Its not just one incident. This person has made many derogatory remarks.  Would you accept that kind of behavoir?. I'm sure you wouldn't like to be degraded like that

Comment: @user2704180 Agreed, the options you're left with are certainly not the best ones. Probably the best here is to ignore him and hope you do not have to work together often. There are few other solutions that would not escalate the issue further.

Comment: It's not your job to put them down. And as the people who are responsible to do so (HR) isn't doing it, you don't really have other option other than let it go and ignore the person. BTW changing job IS a solution. You may find better HR or better co-workers. And if you keep run into people like that, try to find out if you did something wrong to those people.

Comment: @Alic. I had a one on one with the person and tried to solve the problem amicably. When i asked do you have a problem with me, they just respond with. No

Comment: Yep, just ignore then. And if you can't avoid that and HR doesn't do anything. Find a new job.

Comment: Indeed. If companies should just list their staff turnover :-). My previous employers chairman said the door is always open. So maybe i'll go back to that company

Comment: Have you been documenting these incident? That there has been more than one,  is something you should include in your question, as it changes it significantly.

Comment: I've decided that i'd rather avoid politics. Not worth the trouble. The admin may close this ticket

Comment: Either you're a woman, and this was a deliberate gendered insult and is therefore harassment, or you're not and your co-worker is just really bad at snappy comebacks. 

Side note (IANAL), but in most countries to take legal action against your employer you'd need to demonstrate that they have a culture that fosters a pattern of behaviour; something that isn't demonstrated by this one isolated incident.  If HR don't take your complaint seriously, that might demonstrate such a culture though.  Speak to a lawyer.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, isn't abuse a form of unethical behavior?

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom Not a woman. I usually can handle difficult people. But if the person keeps making negative remarks on a daily basis stating how useless you are. It adds up and i have limit to how much nonsense I'm willing to take. Anyway, got new job. Will take this as a lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear violation of harassment rights. You should have a meeting with your manager and HR about the problem.

If you don't feel physically threatened by the person, when it happens next respond calmly with "your comments are harassment and must stop." If you do feel physically threatened *do not engage*. It's not worth getting broken bones over. Sticks and stones, et al.

Comment: Not threatened by him. It's just that these kind of things plays on your subconscious mind. I know I'm very skilled at what I do. I suspect this person might be a narcissist. Anyway this company has a very high staff turnover in the department i work in

Comment: The high turnover suggest something. Find a new job!

Comment: Just tired of corporates with their red-tape and bureaucracy. If i could make enough money free-lancing i would rather do that

Answer (score -1):

This is hardly worth the effort of going to HR. Laugh it off and remember this clown. If it escalates then that is another matter.

You should have verbally riposted in the first instance. You were asking for a nasty comeback by your initial reply and shouldn't have made that comment unless you were prepared to back it up then and there.

Making a fuss over 'Are you sure, you look like one.' may or may not get him in trouble, but it will definitely make you look weak and whiny. Save your battles for something more concrete. If you must, then mention it to your manager, a good manager would have a quiet word with the chap and warn him privately.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll keep that in mind and rather avoid the person

Comment: If this particular case is just a single occurance it "could" be seen as a co-worker doing the whole punch back and forth routine. Some people get closer to each-other by lightly insulting each-others. This seems to have gone past that line, but unless it happens more than once, I would ignore it myself. If you don't like it, **tell him**. If he refuses, THEN go to HR.

Comment: I don't want to dismiss the issue, because it clearly bothered you enough to ask the question, but based on the conversation you used as an example, it sounds to me like he could be a socially inept person trying to banter a little.   I've worked with many people who think they are being funny with co-workers and it just comes off flat.   I would probably just ignore him, I certainly wouldn't see harassment if I were in that conversation.   Making noise about it will most likely draw attention to your thin skin rather than your co-worker.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If it was one occurrence i would let it slide, but because the person has made numerous uncalled for remarks. I get the point though. Its better to avoid people like this